# Handle swift throw in closure in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've an objective-c function that looks like below

`+ (void) invokeSortingWithClassName: (NSString*) className functionName: (NSString*) functionName closure: (id(^)(NSArray* arr))closure;`

and I've to call this method from a swift class. The swift code that calls this method looks like below

```
SortHandler.invokeSorting(withClassName: className, functionName: functionName, closure:
{
    args in 
    let something = unwrap(args!)
    do
    {
        let returnValue = try closure(something as NSArray!) //this is another closure coming as a parameter in the function in which this code is written and this throws
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw error

    }
    return "-1" as! T
})
```

At the start of closure definition, I get this attached error
[image]

Essentially, this closure throws an error and I am not sure, how to handle this error in objective-c definition of this function. Please help me fix this error

Comment: Your closure can't throw an error. You will need to resort to simply returning `nil` to indicate failure or even causing a runtime exception depending on how severe the problem is. Also a return after a throw makes no sense.

Comment: Why cannot a closure throw an error? Is there any Apple document supporting it or link to any other blog/SO post?

Comment: *A closure* can throw,  but *this closure* cannot; it is not declared to throw  (which is what the error message is telling you) and it can't be declared to throw since it is declared in an Objective-C class and Objective-C knows nothing of Swift exceptions.

Comment: Exactly this is my question - how can I declare the same in objective-c? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There is a way to handle it: https://www.uraimo.com/2015/11/03/error-handling-from-objective-c-to-swift-2-and-back/ - but, I am not able to solve it for closures.

Answer (score 3):

While a closure can be declared with `throws`, this closure has not been declared with `throws`, so your closure cannot throw - this is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Since the function is declared in Objective-C, the function signature can't be changed to include `throws` as Objective-C doesn't know anything about Swift exceptions.

The standard way in which error handling is translated between Swift and Objective-C is for the Objective-C block to receive an `&NSError` parameter.

If you have the ability to change the Objective-C method signature, it should be declared as

```
+(void) invokeSortingWithClassName: (NSString* _Nullable) className functionName: (NSString* _Nullable) functionName closure: (id _Nullable (^_Nullable)(NSArray* _Nullable arr, NSError* _Nullable * _Nullable error))closure;
```

This will allow you to `throw` from swift with the error being received via the `error` parameter in Objctive-C.

If you cannot change the method signature, then you will need to catch the exception in your closure and simply return an 'error' value, such as `nil`

Comment: Is there an importance in using nullable here? because, I tried same solution without nullable and it did not work.

Comment: The nullable lets Swift know which parameters are optional. It is best practice to include it even with pure Objective-C

Comment: I tried the same thing, but it is not working - I'm still getting the same compile error.